# Numerically Integrate a function

Tags: numerical-integration

I Numerically integrated a Dirac Delta function and created a table for range of values.

> Table[NIntegrate[(1/Pi) (0.000025/(x^2 + 0.000025^2)), {x, -10 + 
>       i, -10 + (i + 1)}], {i, 1, 10, 1}]

and then plotted it. My question is, for the graph that I generated, can I numerically integrate the curve that I get in the graph for similar range?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163169/numerical-integration-dirac-delta-function; also http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1264536, http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1263284, http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1257837, and http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1240835

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has already answered somewhere else and user is just reluctant to read.

Answer (score 1):

Your list, extended a little:

```
dx = 1;
ilist = Table[
  NIntegrate[(1/Pi) (0.000025/(x^2 + 0.000025^2)), {x, -10 + i, -10 + (i + dx)}],
  {i, 1, 15, dx}]
(*  {1.10524*10^-7, 1.42103*10^-7, 1.8947*10^-7, 2.65258*10^-7, 3.97887*10^-7, 6.63146*10^-7, 1.32629*10^-6, 3.97887*10^-6, 0.499992, 0.499992, 3.97887*10^-6, 1.32629*10^-6, 6.63146*10^-7, 3.97887*10^-7, 2.65258*10^-7}  *)
```

Integral of the list:

```
i2list = Accumulate[ilist]*dx
(*  {1.10524*10^-7, 2.52627*10^-7, 4.42097*10^-7, 7.07355*10^-7, 1.10524*10^-6, 1.76839*10^-6, 3.09468*10^-6, 7.07355*10^-6, 0.499999, 0.999991, 0.999995, 0.999996, 0.999997, 0.999998, 0.999998}  *)
```

Plots of both:

```
ListLinePlot[{ilist, i2list}, DataRange -> {-9, -9 + Length@ilist - 1}]
```

Or just the second:

```
ListLinePlot[i2list, DataRange -> {-9, -9 + Length@i2list - 1}]
```

First plot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Why *numerically* when you can do it explicitly:

```
Integrate[(1/π) (0.000025/(x^2 + 0.000025^2)), 
     {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

(* 1 *)

or numberically:

```
NIntegrate[(1/π) (0.000025/(x^2 + 0.000025^2)), 
     {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

(* 1 *)